# How do I set and unset together with aggregate-update in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('name').update({"bid":"3860"},
{
    [ 
    {"$set":
        { "tl" :
            { $add : 
                [   
                    {
                      $multiply: ["$intField", 24*60*60*1000]
                    },
                    "$dateField"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$unset": {'intField' : 1}}
    ]
    
}
}
)
```

I am able to do `$set`. I am trying to do `$unset` also in single call.

is it possible? Mongo Version is 4.2. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. There is a small mistake that `$update` aggregation operator accepts either `a string or an array`.

```
db.getCollection('name').update({
  "bid": "3860"
},

  [
    {
      "$set": {
        "tl": {
          $add: [
            {
              $multiply: [
                "$intField",
                24*60*60*1000
              ]
            },
            "$dateField"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unset": 'int2Field' -->change here
    } 
  ]

})
```

It is not same as `$unset update` operator syntax. It is `$unset aggregate` operator format.

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: Can I use the same field in $set and $unset , because I am using the same field, unset is success but $set is not working as expected

Comment: @Mano [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62932137/6094348)

Comment: @Yousaf Do you have idea about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955858/update-aggregate-java-mongodb-update)?

Answer (score 0):

This update with aggregation pipeline will remove the `intField` field  from the document using the [REMOVE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.REMOVE) aggregation system variable:

```
db.set.update( 
  { },
  [ 
    { 
       $set: { 
         t1: { $add: [ { $multiply: ["$intField", 24*60*60*1000 ] }, "$dateField" ] }, 
         intField: "$$REMOVE" 
       } 
    } 
  ] 
)
```

Comment: @Gibbs What is it not updating? Is there an error? It works fine when run from `mongo` shell. The Update with  Aggregation pipeline works with MongoDB v4.2 or higher only. Also, you need to try with an input document like this: `{ "_id" : 1, "intField" : 25, "dateField" : ISODate("2020-07-16T09:43:03.954Z") }`. Also, note that `set` in the `db.set.update` is the name of the collection (you can use your substitution).

Comment: @Gibbs And, the resulting document would be like this: `{ "_id" : 1, "dateField" : ISODate("2020-07-16T09:43:03.954Z"), "t1" : ISODate("2020-08-10T09:43:03.954Z") }`. Note the `intField` is _removed_ or _unset_.

Comment: Yes, I have 4.2 version. I tried the same from robo 3t. Let me check once again.