# Can same field be used in $sert, $unset of update(aggregate)

Tags: mongodb

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930770/how-do-i-set-and-unset-together-with-aggregate-update-in-mongodb)

I couldn't explain the reason why the same field cannot be used in `update(aggregate)` in the order of `set` then `unset`.

That looks valid to me at first sight. Since aggregation operator`[]` is  mentioned, I believe that `$set` can use that  `$intField` and then it can `$unset`.

```
db.getCollection('name').update({
  "bid": "3860"
},
{
  [
    {
      "$set": {
        "tl": {
          $add: [
            {
              $multiply: [
                "$intField",
                24*60*60*1000
              ]
            },
            "$dateField"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unset": 'intField' //Here
    } 
  ]
}
})
```

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same field in `$set` and `$unset` stages of update aggregation pipeline.

You have a syntax error in your query. Second argument to `.update()` function should be an array instead of an object. Remove the curly braces around `[]` and the query will work.

```
db.getCollection('name').update(
   {"bid": "3860"},
   [
       {
         "$set": {
            "tl": {
               $add: [
                  {
                     $multiply: ["$intField", 24*60*60*1000 ]
                  },
                  "$dateField"
               ]
             }
          }
       },
       { "$unset": 'intField' } 
  ]
);
```

Comment: How does it work even if I provide `[]` inside `{}`

Comment: I don't think it works if you pass an object as second argument when using update aggregation. All the examples given at [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), pass an array as second argument instead of an object.