# Mongodb Java - Update document replacing a string in field

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am looking for a way to update a document replacing a substring of a field with another value.
For example, in my database i have the following field:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "value": "Old text in the document"
}
```

To update the field i would simply do somehting like this

```
        MongoClient client = ...init client mongodb
        try (ClientSession session = MongoSession.createSession(client)) {
            session.startTransaction(TransactionOptions.builder().writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY).build());
            MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test_db");

            MongoCollection<FileEntity> filesDB = database.getCollection("my_collection", MyClass.class);
            Bson query = Filters.and(Filters.eq("_id", 1));
            Bson updates = Updates.set("value", "New text in the document");

            filesDB.updateOne(session, query, updates);
            session.commitTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error: ", e);
        } finally {
            logger.debug("Success");
        }
```

And this would result in:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "value": "New text in the document"
}
```

But this would require that i know the current value of the field, but in my case i don't.
So i am trying to find a way to say something like

```
Bson updates = Updates.set("value", "$value.replace(\"Old\", \"New\")");
```

Is this possible?
The java driver of mongodb i have is version 3.12.10 and my mongodb server version is v4.2.12.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have 4.4+, you can use $replaceOne or $replaceAll

Comment: But how do i do it in java, could you explain any further please?

Comment: [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955858/update-aggregate-java-mongodb-update)